# c# regex replace problems with dynamic matches?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

So I have a long string where I have "reserved words" that I need to be replaced by their value from the db.

```
eg.

string text = "You're salary for the month of ((month)) is ((salary))
```

Now what I did was to match each and every reserved word and then search through my dataset and then replace those with their value

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"(?<=\(\().*?(?=\)\))");
foreach(Match match in ex.Matches(body)){           
                string valuefromset = values.FirstOrDefault(val => val.Variable == match.Value).Value;
                    var pattern = @"(("+match.Value+"))";
                    body = Regex.Replace(body, pattern, valuefromset, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
            }
```

Now what's happening is this

```
text = "You're salary for the month of ((April)) is (($10000))";
```

I wasn't sure as to why the pattern will just get the words and not the tags. Should I be using another regex but with the specific value? Having the specific reserved word is significant in the pattern that's why I used that, wasn't really sure what i was doing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nothing directly related, but you should use "Your" instead of "You're".

Comment: Is it unknown if Tokens (reserved words) exist in a string?  Are there a lot of potential Tokens?  It seems like using StringBuilder's .Replace method would be more efficient and less complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you don't escape the slashes in the replace regex

```
var pattern = @"(("+match.Value+"))";
                ^^               ^^
```

you are not matching them, you create two groups. Try this:

```
var pattern = @"\(\("+match.Value+"\)\)";
```

Comment: oh my bad it did work! i; was doing a string pattern and was giving me a "unrecognized escape" error when i do the closing paren. thanks!!